# Strange point lies on common tangent of 9-point circle and incircle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle, with medial triangle $DEF$ and intouch triangle $PQR$. Let $J$ be the midpoint of $\overline{AD}$, and let $BJ$ meet $AP$ at $K$. Let $X$ be the point on ray $\overrightarrow{CB}$ such that $CX=CA$. Let the line through $K$ parallel to $BC$ meet $AX$ at $U$. Let $RU$ meet $BC$ at $T$. Prove that $T$ lies on the common tangent of the nine-point circle and the incircle of $\triangle ABC$.
>
> [image]

I have a proof with barycentric coordinates. We can compute $K=(2(s-b):s-c:s-b)$, $X=(0:b:a-b)$, $U=(a-b+c:b:a-b)$ and $T=(0:a-c:a-b)$. The common tangent of the nine-point circle and incircle has equation $$(a-b)(a-c)x+(b-c)(b-a)y+(b-c)(a-c)z=0,$$ and the result follows.

However, as you might guess, I'm interested in a synthetic solution to this problem.

Comment: Oh boy! what a problem, so many conditions xD. I'm usually a big fan of classical geometry problems so I might give it a shot. Sounds fun!

Comment: This is the [Feuerbach Point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FeuerbachPoint.html).

Comment: @EdPegg Unfortunately not. The Feuerbach point is where the incircle and nine-point circle touch. $T$ is just some point on their common tangent. It is not a triangle centre. Its definition is not symmetrical -- when choosing $AD$ we had three medians to choose from, and there are two choices of $X$ (the other having $BX=BA$).

Comment: Also asked on (AoPS)[https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2256593p17425626] and https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1266869

Answer (score 4):

The question has been asked and answered at [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u247660h2256593p17425626).  User amar_04 gives a synthetic proof.  Reproduced here, in case the URL breaks.

> Just use Menelaus repeatedly
>
> $\textbf{LEMMA 1:-}$   The Tangent to the Incircle at the Feuerbach
> Point and the Nagel Line of $\Delta ABC$ are Isotomic Lines.
> **Proof:-** See Theorem 10 [here](https://jcgeometry.org/Articles/Volume1/JCG2012V1pp23-31.pdf)
>
> $\textbf{LEMMA 2:-}$ Let $\tau_1,\tau_2$ be two Isotomic Lines in
> $\angle A$ cutting $BC$ at $X,Y$. Then $BX=CY$
>
> **Proof:-**   Let $\tau_1$ cut $\overline{AB},\overline{AC}$ at $\{P,M\}$ and let $\tau_2$ cut $\overline{AB},\overline{AC}$ at $Q,N$.
> Apply Menelaus Theorem on $\Delta ABC$ cut by the transversals
> $\tau_1,\tau_2$
> $$\begin{align*}\frac{CX}{XB}\cdot\frac{BP}{PA}\cdot\frac{AM}{MC}=-1=\frac{BY}{YC}\cdot\frac{CN}{NA}\cdot\frac{AQ}{QB}&\implies\frac{CX}{XB}=\frac{BY}{YC}\\ &\implies\frac{CB}{XB}=\frac{CB}{YC}\\ &\implies
> BX=CY\end{align*}$$
>
> $\textbf{LEMMA 3:-}$  If the Tangent $(\ell)$ to the Incircle at the
> Feuerbach point of $\Delta ABC$ cuts $\overline{BC}$ at $X$. Then
> $BX=\frac{a(b-a)}{b+c-2a}$
>
> **Proof:-**   Let $G,N_a$ be the Centroid and Nagel Point of $\Delta ABC$ and let $\overline{AG}\cap\overline{BC}=\{M\}$ and
> $\overline{AN_a}\cap\overline{BC}=\{P\}$. Let the Nagel Line of
> $\Delta ABC$ cut $\overline{BC}$ at $Y$. Now applying Menelaus Theorem
> on $\Delta AMP$ cut by the Nagel Line gives
>
> \begin{align*}\frac{PY}{YM}\cdot\frac{MG}{GA}\cdot\frac{AN_a}{N_aP}=-1
>  &\implies\frac{PY}{YM}=\frac{2(s-a)}{a}\\
>  &\implies\frac{PM}{MY}=\frac{2s-3a}{a}\\
>  &\implies\frac{\frac{a}{2}-(s-b)}{MY}=\frac{2s-3a}{a}\\ &\implies
>  MY=\frac{ab-ac}{2(b+c-2a)}\\ &\implies CY=MY+CM\\
>  &=\frac{ab-ac}{2(b+c-2a)}+\frac{a}{2}\\
>  &=\frac{a(b-a)}{b+c-2a}\end{align*}
> Now by $\textbf{LEMMA 1}$ we get
> that $\ell$ and the Nagel Line are Isotomic Lines and if
> $\ell\cap\overline{BC}=X$. Then from $\textbf{LEMMA 2}$ we get
> $CY=BX=\frac{a(b-a)}{b+c-2a}$.
>
> ---
>
> Now come back to the Problem at hand. Applying Menelaus Theorem on
> $\Delta ADP$ cut by the transversal $\overline{BI}$ we get
> $$\frac{DB}{BP}\cdot\frac{PK}{AK}\cdot\frac{AJ}{JD}=-1\implies\frac{AK}{PK}=\frac{a}{2(s-b)}=\frac{AU}{XU}$$
> Again by Menelaus Theorem we get
> $$\frac{XT}{TB}\cdot\frac{BR}{RA}\cdot\frac{AU}{XU}=-1\implies
> > \frac{BX}{TB}=\frac{2s-3a}{a}\implies TB=\frac{a(b-a)}{b+c-2a}$$ So by
> $\textbf{LEMMA 3}$ get that $T\in$ on the Tangent to the Incircle at
> the Feuerbach Point. $\blacksquare$